# $_SESSION across muliple virtual hosts

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have learned that if I share a server with another host (which I do, as I have a virtualhost), then all the hosts share the same $_SESSION is the same across all the hosts.

Does it meant that other hosts can access some of the variables that I store in the $_SESSION?

Comment: I'm unsure if `$_SESSION`s are carried across virtual hosts (depends on your provider, if they link them together or not), but as long as you're connecting to the same database, you can just cookies (store a random identifier that links to different pieces of data).

Comment: angelcool.net, but this ID is a rather long number which is randomly generated, doesn't it mean that the chances that my co-host gets the same number are rather slim?

Comment: it's not about apache virtual hosts, it's about php session storage.

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of the following:

```
echo ini_get('session.save_handler');
echo ini_get('session.save_path');
```

If your save_handler is `files` and your save_path is a common directory like `/var/lib/php5` then you're likely sharing session storage with other users on the server. You're still protected by the nature of the session hash id, but if you have sensitive information you might want to make a change. You could either change the save_handler to something like sqlite and provide your own local database file, or simply change save_path to a directory that's owned by you and has minimal permissions. You can change save_path in a .htaccess file:

```
php_value session.save_path = '/path/to/my/session/directory'
```

Or in your PHP source:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', '/path/to/my/session/directory');
```

Edit: Realistically though, if you have information sensitive enough to warrant this change, then you should be using a VPS and not a shared server.

Comment: The first thing, if not the only, I would consider for _save_handler_ alternatives is _memcached_. Other than that you have a perfect answer IMHO. You've got my upvote.

Comment: On a private server, agreed. However, I'm guessing it's probably not very likely you'll have access to a private memcache daemon on a shared server. (But it's been ages since I used shared servers, so who knows.)

Answer (score 0):

> Does it meant that other hosts can access some of the variables that I store in the $_SESSION?

I would say yes if the session id is the same and if using default configuration for sessions. In regards the session id being large, the chances of hijacking are pretty low, but then again anything is possible, even when using a single *virtual host*. It all depends on your particular circumstances.

But for all practical purposes I will dare to say you will be ok.

Good luck!